# Array performance for millions of records

Tags: c#

I have 2 arrays of equal size and I want to perform some logic by looping through. It works fine for small size arrays but hangs when I load millions of items in the array

I have tried to use Parallel.ForEach but no luck there. here's my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < items1.Length - 1; i++)
    {
       for (int j = i + 1; j < items1.Length; j++)
         {
           if (((items1[i] < items1[j]) & (items2[i] < items2[j])) | ((items1[i] > items1[j]) & (items2[i] > items2[j])))
                    {
                        values1++;
                    }
            else if (((items1[i] > items1[j]) & (items2[i] < items2[j])) | ((items1[i] < items1[j]) & (items2[i] > items2[j])))
                    {
                        values2++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I re-write this to improve performance when data in the array is over a million?

Comment: Where is `items2` coming from?

Comment: What you have at the moment is an N^2 problem (the complexity and time increases as the square of the number of items). Start by setting down what you are trying to do, then see if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Items2 is the second array of the same size. Both arrays (items1 and items2) contain more than a million records

Comment: Convert it to List and Use PLINQ

Answer (score 0):

With parallelism and some small optimizations it becomes almost 4 times faster.

```
Random random = new Random(0);
int[] items1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 5000)
    .OrderBy(n => random.Next()).ToArray(); // Suffled numbers 1-5000
int[] items2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 5000)
    .OrderBy(n => random.Next()).ToArray(); // Suffled numbers 1-5000
long values1 = 0;
long values2 = 0;

var options = new ParallelOptions()
    { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };
Parallel.For(0, items1.Length - 1, options,
() => (0L, 0L),
(i, state, local) =>
{
    var (localValues1, localValues2) = local;
    var items1_i = items1[i];
    var items2_i = items2[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < items1.Length; j++)
    {
        var items1_j = items1[j];
        var items2_j = items2[j];
        if (((items1_i < items1_j) && (items2_i < items2_j))
            || ((items1_i > items1_j) && (items2_i > items2_j)))
        {
            localValues1++;
        }
        else if (((items1_i > items1_j) && (items2_i < items2_j))
            || ((items1_i < items1_j) && (items2_i > items2_j)))
        {
            localValues2++;
        }
    }
    return (localValues1, localValues2);
}, local =>
{
    var (localValues1, localValues2) = local;
    Interlocked.Add(ref values1, localValues1);
    Interlocked.Add(ref values2, localValues2);
});
Console.WriteLine($"values1: {values1}, values2: {values2}");
```

Output:

> values1: 6282046, values2: 6215454

Comment: I can't work this out in c#. The 0L is not accepted so are the variables localValues1, localValues2. Did you validated in .net?

Comment: About 0L, the [suffix L](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long#literals) denotes a long. I guess that you are using long integers to avoid overflow. About the variables `localValues1, localValues2`, are [deconstructed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct#deconstructing-a-tuple) from a `ValueTuple<long, long>`. If you use a C# version earlier than 7.0 then you can use a `Tuple<long, long>` object instead.

Comment: Thanks for that, pure class! I have installed with Install-Package System.ValueTuple and that fixed the issue. However you are passing by ref values1 and values2 where do you declare these? and what values they take? the code still fails to return the right result even if I declare values1 and values2

Comment: @GarryA I updated the code with the missing declarations, and some random input data. I also included the output produced by this set of data. Your code generates the same output.